# SVG toggle color on click and returns at original color when other svg is clicked

Tags: svg, colors, path, position, toggle

I would like to toggle the color of a svg nav pad on click but only rollover works.
I'm not familiar with js (I've written my first jQuery declaration yesterday). Is this possible with html only? I've read all relative posts but no one gives me the answer. When an arrow is clicked, it becomes red, and when another is clicked it must return to its original color. js script works fine (thanks to RAdesign) but color toggles on one element. if I extend it to other elements, it doesn't toggle between other elements like a nav pad does.
Thanks,
Philippe.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <svg>
        <g transform="translate(210,105)">
            <polygon id="right" fill="#50C2BA" x="200" y="100" points="50,0 100,50 50,100 0,100 0,0"/></g>
          <g transform="translate(0,105)">
              <polygon id="left" fill="#50C2BA" x="0" y="100" points="0,50 50,0 100,0 100,100 50,100"/></g>
          <rect id="center" fill="#50C2BA" x="105" y="105" width="100" height="100" /> 
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>      

$('#right').on("click", function() {
    $(this).css({ fill: "red" });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your SVG-Code?

Comment: Funny ! I've found for the first part of the question ... so I was editing the title in order to modify my asking... and the post has gone! Thanks for your so fast response. I have simply added the transformation parameters and it worked. "<g transform="translate(210,105)">
  <polygon id="right" fill="#50C2BA" x="200" y="100" points="50,0 100,50 50,100 0,100 0,0"/></g>" ...But now I'm fighting with the color toggle :°)

Comment: If you want to have a permanent effect i.e. something stays the same colour after you stop hovering then javascript is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to toggle-on-click the fill color of the path:

```js
$(".colorize").on("click", function() {
  $(".colorize").removeClass("red");
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <svg>
        <g transform="translate(210,105)">
            <polygon class="colorize" id="right" fill="#50C2BA" x="200" y="100" points="50,0 100,50 50,100 0,100 0,0"/></g>
          <g transform="translate(0,105)">
              <polygon class="colorize" id="left" fill="#50C2BA" x="0" y="100" points="0,50 50,0 100,0 100,100 50,100"/>             </g>
          <rect class="colorize" id="center" fill="#50C2BA" x="105" y="105" width="100" height="100" /> 
        </g>
      </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I put the script before the <body> but it doesn't work...(I've added js declaration in the <head>)

Comment: Put the script at the end of your HTML document, it needs to be loaded after your SVG is rendered. Otherwise the selector will not find it, of course.

Comment: Thanks. It works now... but only on itself. I wanted it to toggle between all elements: when I click on one green arrow, it becomes red, and if I click on another, the other becomes red and the previous retrieves it's original green color.

Comment: @3dOxyd alright, I will update my answer with some example code for that.